# SQL Server Check If Stored Procedure Contains WITH(NOLOCK)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to write a C# application to check the selected stored procedure for some criteria. For example if the stored procedure contains 5 select queries the same query must contais 5 `with(nolock)` (select for temp tables except).

How can I do this via C#? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know why you are searching for nolocks hints but I can advise you to read about it because nolock is maybe the most misused feature in TSQL

Comment: You'd better read something about locks and `NOLOCK`, it's pros and cons, what "magic" it does and why in most cases it's usage is senseless.

Comment: I think that this is a valid question. I agree that using NOLOCK is not a good idea but it is only an example. According to the question @user2979085 wants to validate stored procedures against many criteria and he wants to do it in C#. These are quite specific requirements. Now I'm guessing but this can be needed to validate the code during a build for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sys.objects` to query SQL Server's metadata in order to analyze SP's definition like a text. In your case you can create query such a listed below and check its results from C# app:

```
SELECT object_definition(object_id) as [sp definition]
, schema_name(schema_id) [schema]
, name
, type_desc
FROM sys.objects
where object_definition(object_id) like '%select%select%select%'
and type_desc = 'SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE'
```

OR

```
SELECT object_definition(object_id) as [sp definition]
, schema_name(schema_id) [schema]
, name
, type_desc
FROM sys.objects
where object_definition(object_id) like '%NOLOCK%'
and type_desc = 'SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE'
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the question is.

You obviously need to parse the SQL (because NOLOCK can also be in a comment).

And to get the source of a stored procedure - well, use something like

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection())
{
    sqlConnection.ConnectionString = yourConnectionStringHere;
    sqlConnection.Open();
    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("sys.sp_helptext", sqlConnection);
    sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@objname", "stored_proc_name_here");
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    sqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand = sqlCommand;
    sqlDataAdapter.Fill(ds);
    return DataTableToString(ds.Tables[0]);;
}
```

although I would never touch the sql server because I keep the source outside in version control, so a Visual Studio plug in would be the better solution.